# Check if table contains data for generic types linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

In this code, only at runtime the table type gets its value. I want to check whether the table contains atleast 1 record, then continue the other check. But the condition always returns true.

```cs
public bool findData<T>()
{
    using (DbEntities dbContext = new DbEntities())
    {
        DbSet dbSet = dbContext.Set(typeof(T));
        if (dbSet.Any())
        {
            //this always executes even if table is empty
        }
        else 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you debug what data do you see in dbSet ?

Comment: @Magnus, i see details about the table. Like the name and other attributes. Bt i dont see the data

Comment: Why not `var dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, i guess it's not the issue right?

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of `Any()`? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Any` method on `DbSet<T>` instead of `DbSet`

```
public bool findData<T>()
   where T: class
{
    using (DbEntities dbContext = new DbEntities())
    {
        DbSet<T> dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
        if (dbSet.Any())
            // table has at least 1 record
        else
            // table is empty
    }
}
```

Comment: not good. Getting error, type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter TEntity in generic type or method DbSet<TEntity>

Comment: Add `where T: class` to method definition.

Comment: @user20565161 this is just a guide code. you have to modify it according to your needs

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, yes I have to add a where condition for a field. EmpNo. Every table contains this

Comment: @user20565161 I do not understand what you have added and to which field and why. I'll edit this answer.